# Customizing indentation in makefile mode?

Tags: indentation, makefile-mode

In my makefiles, I prefer the following indentation for continuation lines:

```
FILES:=                \
    file1.cpp          \
    file2.cpp          \
    fileYetAnother.cpp

LIBS:=                 \
    libsth1.so         \
    libelsewhere.so
```

still, makefile mode indents it in the following way (when asked to reindent file or region):

```
FILES:=            \
file1.cpp          \
file2.cpp          \
fileYetAnother.cpp

LIBS:=             \
libsth1.so         \
libelsewhere.so
```

Is it possible to configure it somehow to use the former variant (= indent continuation lines by 4 spaces or tab) ?

Comment: What about `indent-according-to-mode` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on purple_arrows' solution:

```
(defun my-makefile-indent-line ()
  (save-excursion
(forward-line 0)
(cond
 ;; keep TABs
 ((looking-at "\t")
  t)
 ;; indent continuation lines to 4
 ((and (not (bobp))
       (= (char-before (1- (point))) ?\\))
  (delete-horizontal-space)
  (indent-to 4))
 ;; delete all other leading whitespace
 ((looking-at "\\s-+")
  (replace-match "")))))

(add-hook 'makefile-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
    (setq-local indent-line-function 'my-makefile-indent-line)))
```

Comment: The only problem is that this will not work if your file list is indented by TABs, because my code leaves those untouched.

Comment: fix the indentation to 4 is not a good solution, what if the `FILES` and `LIBS` are long, and there is one element after `:=`, and you better align the following elements with the first one after `:=` ?

Comment: Four spaces is what the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  It is possible to configure it, somehow.

(With apologies for the snark.)

Write a function that indents a line the way you want, then set that function as the value of the variable `indent-line-function` for `makefile-mode`.  Something like:

```
(defun my-makefile-indent-line ()
  ...)

(add-hook 'makefile-mode-hook (lambda () (setq-local indent-line-function 'my-makefile-indent-line)))
```

Comment: Well, those 3 dots are sth I am not sure how to fill... But thanks for partial pointer.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using `aggressive-indent-mode`, it helped me to put `makefile-mode` onto the list of `aggressive-indent-excluded-modes`:

```
(global-aggressive-indent-mode)
(add-to-list 'aggressive-indent-excluded-modes 'makefile-mode)
```

Note that this only works with `global-aggressive-indent-mode` turned on.