# Tab is not inserted when indent-line-function is defined

Tags: makefile-mode

I defined `indent-line-function` variable for Makefile corresponding to the problem referred in [the link](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3074/customizing-indentation-in-makefile-mode).
But when this configuration is activated, pressing `TAB` key does not insert tab letter at the point.
How can I fix it ?

Following is from my init.el

```
(defun yh/makefile-indent-line ()
    "https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3074/customizing-indentation-in-makefile-mode"
    (save-excursion
      (forward-line 0)
      (cond
       ;; keep TABs
       ((looking-at "\t")
        t)
       ;; indent continuation lines to 4
       ((and (not (bobp))
             (= (char-before (1- (point))) ?\\))
        (delete-horizontal-space)
        (indent-to 4))
       ;; delete all other leading whitespace
       ((looking-at "\\s-+")
        (replace-match "")))))

  (add-hook 'makefile-mode-hook
            (lambda ()
              (setq-local indent-line-function 'yh/makefile-indent-line))))
```

edit:

The first problem was `indent-region` in Makefile removes tab character at the beginning of all lines. I googled and reached the page linked above, then I just pasted the snippet from the answer into my `init.el` and it makes `indent-region` keep tab characters.

The second problem, which I mentioned in this post, was I could not insert tab character at all by pressing the tab key when `indent-line-function` above is defined. What I thought at that time was "Pressing tab key let emacs insert a tab character in the current position. How function for indentation affect inserting character ?".

Finally, I understand the problem. Tab is assigned to `indent-for-tab-command` function. And the docstring of the function says

> The function called to actually indent the line or insert a tab
> is given by the variable `indent-line-function'.

So I should modify the function I pasted so that it would insert tab character appropriately. The following is my modification

```
(defun yh/makefile-indent-line ()
    "https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3074/customizing-indentation-in-makefile-mode"
    (let ((bol (= (point-beginning-of-line) (point)))
          (empty (string= (yh/current-line) "")))
      (message "-- %s %s %s" bol empty (point))
      (if bol
          (progn (when empty (insert "\t")))
        (save-excursion
          (forward-line 0)
          (cond
           ;; keep TABs
           ((looking-at "\t") t (message "1 %s" (point-max)))
           ;; indent continuation lines to 4
           ((and (not (bobp))
                 (= (char-before (1- (point))) ?\\))
            (delete-horizontal-space)
            (indent-to 4)
            (message "2"))
           ;; delete all other leading whitespace
           ((looking-at "\\s-+")
            (replace-match "")
            (message "3"))
           (t (message "4 %s" (point-max))))))))
```

Actually, this is not the perfect (in some situation, behave badly) but acceptable to me.

Comment: If you expect this code to make the TAB key insert a TAB character, then you seem to have misunderstood the problem defined in "the link".  But maybe you simply haven't described your problem precisely enough?

Comment: Usually in modes where the TAB key function is overridden, one types C-Q C-I to obtain a tab character. Similarly with C-Q C-J for newlines when using "query-replace" and friends.

Comment: Thank you for @Stefan. I understand the problem.

Comment: Thank yuo @Ben , too.